# Apache Tomcat Logs with custom directory structure

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, directory

I want to get the Apache Tomcat logs in a **custom directory structure** which should be like below, I was using Apache Tomcat Version 9.0.52.

```
/var/logs/tomcat/yyyy/mm/
/var/logs/httpd/yyyy/mm/
/var/logs/modsecurity/yyyy/mm/
```

Somethings like this in realtime below

`/var/logs/tomcat/2021/10/catalina.out`

`/var/logs/tomcat/2021/10/manager.2021-10-16.log`

`/var/logs/tomcat/2021/10/host-manager.2021-10-16.log`

`/var/logs/tomcat/2021/10/catalina.2021-10-16.log`

`/var/logs/tomcat/2021/10/localhost.2021-10-16.log`

I have changed the Apache Tomcat logging.properties as below, but all of the logs are creating in `/var/logs/tomcat/`  directory, I want to configure the custom directory structure above provided list for all logs files related to Apache Tomcat.

```
############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = /var/log/tomcat/yyyy/
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = "/var/log/tomcat"
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = /var/log/tomcat
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = /var/log/tomcat
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = /var/log/tomcat
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8
```

Also, I have updated catalina.sh file in the tomcat bin directory for saving catalina.out file in `\var\log\tomcat` directory
Kindly Let me know any ideas to achieve this. It will be helpful to others also who are looking for this kind of solution.

Note: Also, I don't want to use **log4j**

Comment: As i know it is opensource,  So : You can  do  everythin what every you want. So it is possible.

Comment: @KUTAYZORLU can you please give me some reference articles or solutions how to do?

Comment: Server .xml  file my be you can go over XML configuration files 

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="/var/logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

Comment: this book : https://books.google.de/books?id=G6-nAJiUAIMC&pg=PA249&lpg=PA249&dq=tomcat+log+directory+name+change+dynamic+year+date&source=bl&ots=N1LXS-JU2E&sig=ACfU3U1spLNXuoOl4YO4wEkWOepq6ECF1Q&hl=tr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-tvGxhtDzAhVPC-wKHV2qBG4Q6AF6BAgaEAM#v=onepage&q=tomcat%20log%20directory%20name%20change%20dynamic%20year%20date&f=false

Comment: The existing [`Handler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html)s don't offer the feature you are looking for, but you can always write your own handler.

Comment: ooh okay, thanks @PiotrP.Karwasz for the information. I will try to create the handler